# Not recognize Function onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript

Does not recognize the function if I go directly to Button Close Window

Function is activated correctly, if the link to the link that sends to GOOGLE, but if the load is the page and the document in closing the browser tag or in the close button does not work

```html
<body onbeforeunload="return myFunction()">

<p>Close this window, press F5 or click on the link below to invoke the onbeforeunload event.</p>

<a href="https://www.google.com">Click here to go to google </a>
  
<script>
function myFunction() {
  return "Write something clever here...";
}
</script>

</body>
```

I hope that once you find me on the page, without the need to click on an item of the sale and when closing the tab or the browser recognizes the obeforeunload

Comment: The prompt for onbeforeunload is only used (depending on the browser) if the user has interacted with the page beforehand. It is an annoyance prevention feature

Comment: Which browser? Have you tried it in different ones?

Comment: What could you use to identify when you close the page without having previously interacted with the page?

Comment: I tested it in all browsers